# Powershell Script parameters with path names fail invocation

Tags: powershell, batch-file, parameters

I'm calling a PowerShell script from a BAT file:

```
powershell -nologo -file ./Run-Metrics.ps1 1 1 "RWSConsoleOnly" "batch" "RWSConsoleOnly" 3 "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\FXCop\FXCopCmd.exe" "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\Rule Sets\" "14" "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\FxCop\Metrics.exe" "d:\a6\RWS_Test_Batch_XML\Microsoft_Build_XML\trunk"
```

and I'm getting this parse error:

```
Run-Metrics.ps1 : A 
positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Studio'.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Run-Metrics.ps1], ParentCo 
   ntainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Run-Metrics.ps1
```

The parameters for the script are:

```
Param
(
    # AHP Iteration
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,Position=0)]
    [int]$AHPIteration,

    # buildAnalysisCount
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,Position=1)]
    [int]$buildAnalysisCount,

    # buildAnalysisNames
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,Position=2)]
    [string]$buildAnalysisNames,

    # buildAnalysisTypes
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,Position=3)]
    [string]$buildAnalysisTypes,

    # buildAnalysisAsmbs
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,Position=4)]
    [string]$buildAnalysisAsmbs,

    # FXCop Level
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,Position=5)]
    [int]$FXCopLevel,

    # FXCopCmdPath
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,Position=6)]
    [string]$FXCopCmdPath,

    # FXCop Ruleset Path
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,Position=7)]
    [string]$FXCopRulesetPath,

    # Visual Studio Version
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,Position=8)]
    [string]$msvsversion,

    # Metrics Command Path
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,Position=9)]
    [string]$metricsCommandPath,

    # Working Path
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,Position=10)]
    [string]$workingPath
)
```

I don't understand why I'm getting this error. This was working two days ago (at least it was getting into the actual script...) I haven't changed the BAT file or the parameters, just code within the script. I've tried adding more quotes around the parameters that contain paths but that didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was the path that ends in *\Rule Sets\"*. The trailing backslash was escaping the closing quote.